# Display Wordpress child and Parent terms

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I have a 'location' taxonomy, and on the archive pages I wish to display the posts location terms. Each post has one child term, so it is ticked 'New York' under the parent US.

On the front end I wish to display - New York, US

So the child term which is ticked, and then the parent.

At the moment I just have

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location'); ?>
```

Which just shows the ticked term, however I wish it to pull in the parent term too.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24794/get-the-the-top-level-parent-of-a-custom-taxonomy-term

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the parent terms of current post terms

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'location');

foreach ($terms as $term) {
 echo get_term_link( $term ); // get the child term url
 echo get_term_link( $term->parent ); // get parent term url
 $parent = get_term($term->parent, 'location');
 echo $parent->name;
}
```

Comment: How would I add a link to this?

Comment: You can use the `get_term_link()` function. I updated my answer